# Changing resolution of the nyquist plot

Tags: matlab, nyquist

I'm trying to check whether the system represented by
h=tf([1, 1],[1 6 0 0]) is stable by the nyquist criterion.

[but when i put the commend
'nyquist(h)' at the matlab, i get only this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z87Fx.png)

clearly it's not the full sketch. how can i change it could see whole of it?
using the button at the top won't work.

Comment: This nyquist plot is unbounded, it tends to infinity when the frequency tends to 0.

Comment: I know that, but I'm sure that yet there is a way to see whole of it (otherwise it wasn't possible to print those sektches at books etc.)